# A problem occurred when trying to limit the data set

Tags: r, output, limit, tibble

I want to limit the MARPOR data set to these three specific variables. However, when I run the code, I keep getting the results only for two or sometimes three candidates, namely "Anthony Garotinho," "Geraldo Alckmin," and "Jair Bolsonaro." Does someone know how to fix this? Here is the code chunk:

```
`library(haven)


marpor <- haven::read_sav("MPDataset_MPDS2023a (1).sav", encoding = "latin1")

library(dplyr)

selected_candidates <- c("Anthony Garotinho", "Geraldo Alckmin", "José Serra", "Aécio Neves",  
"Jair Bolsonaro")

selected_edate <- as.Date(c("2002-10-06", "2006-10-01", "2010-10-03", "2014-10-05", "2018-10-
07"))

filtered_data <- marpor %>%
  filter(
    (candidatename == "Anthony Garotinho" & edate == selected_edate[1]) | 
    (candidatename == "Geraldo Alckmin" & edate == selected_edate[2]) | 
    (candidatename == "José Serra" & edate == selected_edate[3]) | 
    (candidatename == "Aécio Neves" & edate == selected_edate[4]) | 
    (candidatename == "Jair Bolsonaro" & edate == selected_edate[5])
  ) %>%
  select(candidatename, edate, rile)


filtered_data`
```

I have already tried changing the acute accents to `\'e` and `\u00E9`, but it didn't work.

Comment: `data.frame(candidatename = selected_candidates, edate = selected_edate) %>% left_join(marpor)` might be another way.